# I am not understanding how water passes through root hair cells

Tags: cell-biology, botany, osmosis

Why do people say that water moves into the cell because the water concentration of the cell sap is low ? the cell sap is surrounded by a membrane so if any water moves into the cell it must be because the concentration of water in the cytoplasm is lower than the surroundings. I am thinking that water from the cytoplasm moves into the cell sap solution and as a result , the concentration of water in the cytoplasm decreases so water moves in from the surroundings.

Comment: Maybe people use a bad shortcut of what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmosis is?

Comment: Is ytour question: "What is osmosis?"

Comment: though the situation is similar is same as osmosis in jars; Upvoted and watchlisted. Because one popular explanation for why "osmosis is sort of diffusion" tells; the *"concentration of **water**"* in an aq. solution of something; is **lesser** than *concentration of "**water**"* in pure water! because pure water is 100% water, but an aq. soln of something is not 100% water. So on presence of membrane; pure water (high conc of water) diffuse into soln (low water). But I couldn't accept it anymore when I came to know that, adding little salt to water make it contract (contd)...

Comment: ...(contd)... [link](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/why-does-water-volume-decrease-when-salt-is-added) so the concentration of water (moles per liter) actually increased still water would go to the salt side from pure-water side. It became clear only when it was explained to me with concept of free-energy changes in mixing.